# encoding response from httpClient.PostAsync

Tags: c#, post, encoding, windows-phone-8.1

I have some problem with the encoding of a response from my server.

I send this string from my android client and also from my windows phone client :

```
{"debug":"false","action":"test","option":{"0":"È","1":"è"}}
```

in the android client I see this response

```
 [{"id_option":73,"description":"\u00e8"},{"id_option":74,"description":"\u00c8"}]
```

and this is ok, but in the Windows Phone client I receive this response:

```
[{"id_option":75,"description":"\u00c3\u0088"},{"id_option":76,"description":"\u00c3\u00a8"}]
```

the server is the same.

The windows phone comunication part is the follow:

```
    var obj = new JsonObject();
            obj.Add("debug", JsonValue.CreateStringValue("false"));
            obj.Add("action", JsonValue.CreateStringValue("test"));
            obj.Add("option", optionJson);   
 var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                                {
                                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("values", obj.Stringify()),                  
                                };
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(urlPath, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Debug.WriteLine(responseString);
```

Comment: Can you check the exact request/response in both cases? (for example using fiddler). Maybe you send different accept or encoding values.

Comment: I think that c# send an UTF16 encoded string...but I don't know how can I change the encoding